# There's a memory leak in my flutter app, I've used to states..one is setState() and another is setStateSB() for child container

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having issue with memory leaks, I've tried using dispose() method but it doesn't seem to help.

Error snapshot:

[image]

What can I try next?

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setStateSB) {
            taskController.addListener(() {
              final isButtonActive = taskController.text.isNotEmpty;
              if (mounted) {
                setStateSB(() {
                  isButtonActive ? isButtonActive : isButtonActive;
                });
              }
            });
```

Comment: where did you call this `showModalBottomSheet` ? based on my exp, this error happend when we close page before call the function. which caused error in the widget tree

Comment: I suppose you have not removed the listener at the correct place after your bottom sheet disappears.